# Index out of range in implementation of a variation of mergesort algorithm in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I have done a variation of my merge sort algorithm in python, based on what I've learnt from the CLRS book, and compared it with the implementation done on the introductory computer science book by MIT. I cannot find the problem in my algorithm, and the IDLE gives me an index out of range although everything looks fine to me. I'm unsure if this is due to some confusion in borrowing ideas from the MIT algorithm (see below).

```
lista = [1,2,3,1,1,1,1,6,7,12,2,7,7,67,4,7,9,6,6,3,1,14,4]   

def merge(A, p, q, r):
    q = (p+r)/2
    L = A[p:q+1]
    R = A[q+1:r]

    i = 0
    j = 0

    for k in range(len(A)):

        #if the list R runs of of space and L[i] has nothing to compare
        if i+1 > len(R):
            A[k] = L[i]
            i += 1

        elif j+1 > len(L):
            A[k] = R[j]
            j += 1

        elif L[i] <= R[j]:
            A[k] = L[i]
            i += 1

        elif R[j] <= L[i]:
            A[k] = R[j]
            j += 1

        #when both the sub arrays have run out and all the ifs and elifs done,
        # the for loop has effectively ended

    return A


def mergesort(A, p, r):
    """A is the list, p is the first index and r is the last index for which
        the portion of the list is to be sorted."""
    q = (p+r)/2
    if p<r:
        mergesort(A, p, q)
        mergesort(A, q+1, r)
        merge (A, p, q, r)
    return A

print mergesort(lista, 0, len(lista)-1)
```

I have followed the pseudocode in CLRS as closely as I could, just without using the "infinity value" at the end of L and R, which would continue to compare (is this less efficient?). I tried to incorporate ideas like that in the MIT book, which is to simply copy down the remaining L or R list to A, to mutate A and return a sorted list. However, I can't seem to find what has went wrong with it. Also, I don't get why the pseudo code requires a 'q' as an input, given that q would be calculated as (p+q)/2 for the middle index anyway. And why is there a need to put p

On the other hand, from the MIT book, we have something that looks really elegant.

```
def merge(left, right, compare):
    """Assumes left and right are sorted lists and
compare defines an ordering on the elements.
Returns a new sorted(by compare) list containing the
same elements as(left + right) would contain.
"""
    result = []
    i, j = 0, 0

    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if compare(left[i], right[j]):
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else :
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1

    while (i < len(left)):
        result.append(left[i])
        i += 1

    while (j < len(right)):
        result.append(right[j])
        j += 1

    return result

import operator

def mergeSort(L, compare = operator.lt):
    """Assumes L is a list, compare defines an ordering
on elements of L. 
Returns a new sorted list containing the same elements as L"""
if len(L) < 2:
    return L[: ]
else :
    middle = len(L) //2
left = mergeSort(L[: middle], compare)
right = mergeSort(L[middle: ], compare)
return merge(left, right, compare)
```

Where could I have gone wrong?

Also, I think the key difference in the MIT implementation is that it creates a new list instead of mutating the original list. This makes it quite difficult for me to understand mergesort, because I found the CLRS explanation quite clear, by understanding it in terms of different layers of recursion occurring to sort the most minute components of the original list (the list of length 1 that needs no sorting), thus "storing" the results of recursion within the old list itself.

However, thinking again, is it right to say that the "result" returned by each recursion in the MIT algorithm, which is in turn combined?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: A stack trace is the message that appears when your program goes wrong and tells you where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fundamental difference between your code and the MIT is the conditional statement in the mergesort function. Where your if statement is:

```
if p<r:
```

theirs is:

```
if len(L) < 2:
```

This means that if you were to have, at any point in the recursive call tree, a list that is of `len(A) == 1`, then it would still call `merge` on a size 1 or even 0 list. You can see that this causes problems in the merge function because  then your `L`, `R`, or both sub lists can end up being of size 0, which would then cause an out if bounds index error.

your problem could then be easily fixed by changing your if statement to something alike to theirs, like `len(A) < 2` or `r-p < 2`